# LSTM as learned positional encoding for vor variable sequence length input

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm, transformer, sequence

I'm solving a classification task on a time-series dataset. 
I use a Transformer encoder with learned positional encoding in the form of a matrix of shape
$\mathbb{R}^{seq \times  embedding}$.
Naturally, this leads to the fact that the sequence length that the model can process becomes fixed.
I had an idea to do learned positional encoding with LSTM. 
I.e., we project a sequence of tokens with a linear layer onto an embedding dimension, then feed the embeddings to LSTM layer and then add hidden states to the embedding. 
$x = MLP(x)$
$x = x + LSTM(x)$

Do you think this will have the right effect?
Are there any things to consider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first sight, it should have the right effect. However, [LSTM has limits](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27392/so-whats-the-catch-with-lstm) and it cannot process any kind of timeseries with any size properly.

For instance, if the inputs are too small (sequence length <20), classic RNN might be even better than LSTM (sequence length ~250-500), depending also on the variability of your data.

That's why, the different inputs shall be comparable to have a good prediction, and data scaling could be therefore necessary.

I suggest you to study the [LSTM paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/13853244_Long_Short-term_Memory) to have a good understanding about its limits and how the data is processed.

Otherwise, I would need more information to be more specific about potential solutions.

Note: time series classification can also be done with [dimensional reduction algorithms](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/106987/can-t-sne-be-applied-to-visualize-time-series-datasets).

Comment: What do you mean by "data scaling"? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It could mean data normalization or data modification to fit fix input length. For instance, if you have [23,10,26,32] and [50,68], you will want to change it to [23,10,26,32] and [0,0,50,68] (or using points extrapolation). It depends on your business needs.